# Comment,edit or answer when adding content

Tags: discussion

There is a question on this SE ([Why aren't wands protected better?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123707/why-arent-wands-protected-better)), whose only answer until now is basically a list of reasons why wands aren't better protected.

I thought another possible reason, but I'm confused by how should I proceed.
AFAIK, I could post an answer, write a comment or edit the answer.

If I posted a new answer, it would be something like "I agree with the previous answer, but there is an additional reason: ... ", and because it would be rather short, it may be written as a comment as well.

On the other hand, I know that we can edit answers to add content: see [Are edits supposed to add information/content to an answer?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8126/are-edits-supposed-to-add-information-content-to-an-answer).

What should I do?

Comment: I see you've answered the question already, with what is a good answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/123753 but we don't need to delete this meta question as you could still get a good answer, or answer it yourself with your reasonings.

Comment: I understand, I'm going to wait for an answer. It might be useful another time to me or other users, I guess.

Comment: Adding additional info is fine. I do it all the time with supporting links, book quotes, higher quality video and screenshots. What's not fine is adding something that substantively diverts from the answer given such as a completely new source of info or changing the main thesis/conclusion of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are few things you can do in this case, as you point out-

### Comment

You can leave a comment under the answer, letting the owner of that answer know that there is/are cases that have been missed. The owner of the answer can then choose to edit it in, or ignore it. The downside to this is that comments are ephemeral, and can disappear at any time.

### Edit

This is a little different situation. As can be seen [by a SE meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts), and this from the top voted answer:

> You edit to make things better, clearer, more effective -- never to change meaning.

As Valorum points out in his comment, adding additional supporting information or cases is fine, as long as it doesn't substantially change the essence of the answer. In that case, there is the third option:

### Post a new answer

I would do this in a couple of cases - You've left a comment, and the original answerer has not incorporated it in a reasonable amount of time (Or, if you look at their profile and they haven't been back to the site in an extended period of time).

Or, (and this would be the case with your answer), the new information + supporting material is longer/better/much clearer than the original answer. If you can provide that much information, then it is no longer really a list item addition, but a stand alone candidate. In addition, providing an answer of that quality also improves the site.